# How can I set up a Sequelize singleton with CoffeeScript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm, sequelize.js

I am creating a `npm` package that will act as a singleton to connect to my database. It will ultimately handle other utility type functions and have complex queries built in. I want to use `Sequelize` to connect to my database.

In my package, I have:

```
class Singleton
  @getInstance: ->
    @_instance ?= new @(arguments...)

class MyDb extends Singleton
  constructor: (config) ->
    sequelize = new Sequelize config.database, config.username, config.password,
      dialect: 'postgresql'
      host: config.host
      port: config.port
      logging: false
      define:
        charset: 'utf8'
        collate: 'utf8_general_ci'

    db = {}

    modelPath = "./models"

    files = fs.readdirSync modelPath

    _.each files, (file) ->
      if '.coffee' is path.extname file
        model = sequelize.import path.join modelPath, file
        db[model.name] = model

    Object.keys(db).forEach (modelName) ->
      if 'associate' of db[modelName]
        db[modelName].associate db

    myDb = _.assign db, 
      sequelize: sequelize
      Sequelize: Sequelize

    console.log myDb
    return myDb

module.exports = MyDb
```

I'm obviously doing a lot wrong. Ultimately, I want to use it like this:

```
mydb = require 'mydb'

mydb.connect 'myconnection params', (err) ->
  console.log err if err

# some code and stuff here

mydb.User.find
  where:
    email: 'bob
.complete (err, dbUser) ->
  #whatever

# SOME OTHER FILE THAT GETS CALLED AFTER THE MAIN ONE
mydb = require 'mydb'

mydb.Home.find
  where:
    zip: '12345'
```

How can I set up my package to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton pattern is not necessary in Node.js to accomplish what you're trying to do, though you can still use it if you'd like to. Node.js caches all require() calls, so every time you call require('./mydb') it will return the exact same object or function.

For your code to work, all you need is:

module.exports = new MyDb({ .. connection info .. })

From then on, in your various files, you can call require('./mydb'), and it will return the same instance of your MyDB class (it will NOT execute new MyDb() each time you call require, this is a common mistake!).

Hence, it is common practice when using Sequelize to simply create a file that calls new Sequelize() and export that instance (along with the models, much like you've done).

Comment: How do I have the `connection info` part of it then?

Comment: In your costructor, you are expecting an object config. So I'd assume you'd be doing something along the lines of: new MyDB({ host: localhost, port: database: 'mydb' , etc }) and any other credentials required.

Comment: Right, but if that's in the `module.exports`, then how can I pass that from my calling file?

Comment: In this case, you wouldn't be able to. So you want to export the class, but instantiate in another file? Could you show what you expect that file to look like?

Comment: If you look at the second snippet in my original post, that gives an idea of what that file should look like.

Comment: But sequelize does not have a .connect() method.  The only time you specify your connection credentials is when you instantiate the object. When you perform queries, Sequelize will manage connections for you automatically. The standard practice is to create a seperate file dedicated for creating and exporting a new Sequelize instance (your connection details will be in this file). Then whenever you need to query the database you'd simply call require('mydb'), and perform the query without needing to specify credentials as the db object will already be instantiated.